# Generic method of type <T> at runtime AND storing result in IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, reflection

Before marking it as duplicate, Please note that I have read all these questions including Jon Skeet's answer but still I have an issue.
Links I have gone through and a few more I'm not listing here:

[Instantiate object with reflection and dynamic arguments count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272902/instantiate-object-with-reflection-and-dynamic-arguments-count)

[Instructing a generic to return an object of a dynamic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545807/instructing-a-generic-to-return-an-object-of-a-dynamic-type)

[Is there a way not to use dynamic when instantiating a type that inherits from generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451256/is-there-a-way-not-to-use-dynamic-when-instantiating-a-type-that-inherits-from-g)

**I have searched the same question and realized that providing type T at runtime is not possible because Generic type T must be known at compile time. I understand this but I have the following scenario:**

Basically I want to do this :

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetListing<T>(string entityName)
{
    Entity entity = new Entity { Name = entityName, Action = "Select" };

    ResponsePacket<T> entityViewModel = new ResponsePacket<T>();

    entityViewModel.Records = myHttpClient.GetAllEntities<T>(entity, "10", "0").Content;

    return entityViewModel.Records.AsEnumerable();
}
```

And call it like this :

```
public IEnumerable<myType> CallListing(string entityName)
{
    Type myType = {get type of entityName through some method eg User}
    IEnumerable<myType> result = GetListing<myType>;
    return result;
}
```

---

NOW I have read that this **cannot** be achieved **without reflection** which means I have to create an instance of `GetListing<>` and then tell it through reflection about the `<T>`.

My problem is even if I use reflection to create an instance of `GetListing<myType>` and invoke it at runtime through reflection, **How do I get the returned result of `GetListing<T>` in `IEnumerable<myType>` ?**  Will reflection also provide the result of `IEnumerable<myType>` at runtime ?

From what I know, the returned result of Reflection is an object, How do I cast it to `IEnumerable<myType>`, I **cannot** cast it to IList like this:

`IList returnedresult = (IList)returnedResult` because **my Grid/View page needs a model of `IEnumerable<myType>`** i.e `IEnumerable<User>` OR `IEnumerable<Roles>` which I am hoping to get through reflection. I have to pass a model to my view `@model IEnumerable<GridModel>` where gridmodel will need `IEnumerable<myType>`.

I have also read that **dynamic** is the way to go here, but I dont know how. How will I achieve what I am looking for using dynamic? I have no clue. Please tell me if there is a way to store the returned result of reflected method in an `IEnumerable<myType>`.

If both of these cannot be achieved then please tell me how can I achieve this in some other way.

I dont know the Type of entity at compile time otherwise there would be lots of code replication & if I have 100 entities for which I want to call GetListing() for, I would have to write GetUserListing, GetRolesListing, Get...Listing() and then I would have to explicitly call `GetListing<User>`, `GetListing<Roles>` from inside the GetUserListing, GetRolesListing methods which defeats the purpose.

Comment: "my Grid/View page needs a model of IEnumerable<*Type>" Why is this? If you don't know the type at compile time, what benefit does the page get of having the generic IEnumerable?

Comment: IEnumerable<myType>  i.e IEnumerable<User> or IEnumerable<Roles> which I would get through the reflected returned result if i am able to store it in IEnumerable<myType> .

Comment: Can you work out the Type from `entityName` before the call to `CallListing`?

Comment: @zeppelin Right, my question is why do you ultimately need an `IEnumerable<User>` rather than just an `IEnumerable` if you don't know that the type is going to be `User` at compile time?

Comment: What do you mean by work out? I am hoping to get the type of entity through a string, entityName="User" or "Role" will be provided by user at runtime. For example I will get "User", Then I will try to convert the string "User" to Type User, This type will be stored in myType variable whose datattype will be Type. Then I want to pass this on to GetListing<myType>.

Comment: @BenAaronson My View needs to be strongly typed by the <entity> so that the grid can autogenerate columns based on the <entity> i.e If it gets <User> it will generate columns for User model and so on.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the crux of the issue but I'll try to clarify - where is `entityName` coming from? Can you do this part `Type myType= {get type of entityName through some method eg User}` further up the stack and then you could make `CallListing` generic and simply pass through the generic type parameter?

Comment: @DaveParsons entityName is a string which will be supplied by User at runtime. If entityName = "User" , I will make it Type User using reflection. The Type myType = User can be suplied to CallListing as a parameter too but it would be extracted from a user provided string through reflection.

Comment: @zeppelin Ah, so this is a limitation imposed by third-party code? That's rather irritating. Have you considered keeping everything non-generic right up until the point where you hand over your model to the view, and only then using reflection to get the generic `IEnumerable<MyType>`?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, Keeping it non generic would mean writing separate listing methods for each entity type? I think this would defeat the purpose of what I am aiming for here. Right now I have separate method like GetUserListing , GetRoleListing etc. All the code is same inside these methods except for the Type of entity. I want to create a single method which would do the same thing for different entityTypes which will be supplied at runtime

Comment: But you would still need separate CallListing methods?

Comment: No, CallListing will only get entityName, change the entityName string to Type, store it in myType variable and then will call GetListing<*myType> . CallListing is doing nothing but just converting string entityName to Type and providing myType to GetListing as generic parameter between angle brackets.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking after:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Get<int>("System.Int32").ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(Get<string>("System.String").ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(Get<double>().ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(Get<long>().ToString());
}

public Type TypeResolver(string type)
{
    return Type.GetType(type);
}

public IEnumerable<T> Get<T>(string typeName)
{   
    var type = TypeResolver(typeName);
    var entityStore = new EntityStore();
    return entityStore.GetType().GetMethod("GetAll").MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(entityStore, null) as IEnumerable<T>;
}

public IEnumerable<T> Get<T>()
{
    var entityStore = new EntityStore();
    return entityStore.GetType().GetMethod("GetAll").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T)).Invoke(entityStore, null) as IEnumerable<T>;
}

public class EntityStore
{
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>()
    {
        return new List<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: In your Main() method you are passing <int> , <string> <double> at compile time , And the corresponding GetAll() method is invoked based on these types, But in my issue I dont know the types , For example if I have User I want to call Get<User> . I think in your example Get<int>, Get<string> is the same as writing GetListing<User> or GetListing<Roles> which is not possible because I dont know the type at compile time. Otherwise there would be too many switch case statements in which I would have to list down every possible type that might be called.

Comment: if(entityName=="User"){Console.WriteLine(Get<User>("Models.User").ToString());}else if(...){
    Console.WriteLine(Get<Roles>("Models.Roles").ToString());} else if(..){ ...} else if(...){ Get<..> }.   This would mean i would have to list down every Model like that, I dont wan to do that, I dont know the type at compile time.

Comment: That was just showing you it works. Try the code out before you say it won't work.

Comment: I actually took some time before replying to your post because I wanted to try your code myself and I tried it and then replied here. Please read my comments above and tell me if I misunderstood the given code because I honestly dont know, I tried it, Please read my above two comments and tell me where am I wrong.

Comment: Then what you are asking is impossible. C# doesn't do dynamic dispatch of methods, you need to know which overload of a method is called when compiling. That includes generics. Just because you usually don't see the <T> part in Visual Studio doesn't mean it's not there.